# readline: how to map single bare ESC key in inputrc

Tags: readline

I tried :

ESC: kill-whole-line

and it seems to work, except that 
it breaks other bindings, such as 
the arrow keys.

I also tried:

"\e\e": kill-whole-line

which works, except that it's a double ESC rather than a single one.